# Why am I unable to load my heroku app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm currently going through the Odin Project and just created my first rails app. Now I'm trying to deploy it to Heroku which I've previously done before, but this time it wont load the page. Whenever I run Heroku open in the terminal Safari pops up saying it wont load due to "Too many redirects". I'm unsure of where to start to fix this issue. The Heroku app link is https://damp-ravine-93217.herokuapp.com.
Here is my config/routes.rb file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'author/Sessions'

 resources :articles do
    resources :comments
 end

 resources :tags
 resources :authors
 resources :author_sessions, only: [ :new, :create, :destroy ]
 get 'login'  => 'author_sessions#new'
 get 'logout' => 'author_sessions#destroy'

 root to: 'articles#index'

end
```

And my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end

gem 'sorcery'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.4'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record

# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
gem 'paperclip'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: 
https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
   # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger 
console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> 
anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the 
background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

And here's my Heroku logs:

```
Marcuss-MacBook-Pro:blogger marcus$ heroku logs
2017-10-11T02:59:33.316129+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=damp-ravine-93217.herokuapp.com request_id=1a14b22d-054e-4881-9f50-7138feaa6af9 fwd="68.113.36.43" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=12ms status=302 bytes=806 protocol=https
2017-10-11T02:59:33.313223+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:33.311838 #4]  INFO -- : [1a14b22d-054e-4881-9f50-7138feaa6af9] Started GET "/" for 68.113.36.43 at 2017-10-11 02:59:33 +0000
2017-10-11T02:59:33.314440+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:33.314362 #4]  INFO -- : [1a14b22d-054e-4881-9f50-7138feaa6af9] Processing by ArticlesController#index as HTML
2017-10-11T02:59:33.315819+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:33.315719 #4]  INFO -- : [1a14b22d-054e-4881-9f50-7138feaa6af9] Redirected to https://damp-ravine-93217.herokuapp.com/
2017-10-11T02:59:33.316008+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:33.315911 #4]  INFO -- : [1a14b22d-054e-4881-9f50-7138feaa6af9] Filter chain halted as :require_login rendered or redirected
2017-10-11T02:59:33.316236+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:33.316159 #4]  INFO -- : [1a14b22d-054e-4881-9f50-7138feaa6af9] Completed 302 Found in 2ms
2017-10-11T02:59:33.429473+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:33.429350 #4]  INFO -- : [d2637cad-cd5e-4aa2-b745-5b3a9f29d619] Started GET "/" for 68.113.36.43 at 2017-10-11 02:59:33 +0000
2017-10-11T02:59:33.438373+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:33.438262 #4]  INFO -- : [d2637cad-cd5e-4aa2-b745-5b3a9f29d619] Processing by ArticlesController#index as HTML
2017-10-11T02:59:33.439328+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:33.439251 #4]  INFO -- : [d2637cad-cd5e-4aa2-b745-5b3a9f29d619] Redirected to https://damp-ravine-93217.herokuapp.com/
2017-10-11T02:59:33.439493+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:33.439426 #4]  INFO -- : [d2637cad-cd5e-4aa2-b745-5b3a9f29d619] Filter chain halted as :require_login rendered or redirected
2017-10-11T02:59:33.439657+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:33.439593 #4]  INFO -- : [d2637cad-cd5e-4aa2-b745-5b3a9f29d619] Completed 302 Found in 1ms
2017-10-11T02:59:33.554792+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:33.554668 #4]  INFO -- : [eaf81f4a-ddfc-441b-bf61-537208d2fae1] Started GET "/" for 68.113.36.43 at 2017-10-11 02:59:33 +0000
2017-10-11T02:59:33.555657+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:33.555583 #4]  INFO -- : [eaf81f4a-ddfc-441b-bf61-537208d2fae1] Processing by ArticlesController#index as HTML
2017-10-11T02:59:33.556582+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:33.556508 #4]  INFO -- : [eaf81f4a-ddfc-441b-bf61-537208d2fae1] Redirected to https://damp-ravine-93217.herokuapp.com/
2017-10-11T02:59:33.556750+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:33.556670 #4]  INFO -- : [eaf81f4a-ddfc-441b-bf61-537208d2fae1] Filter chain halted as :require_login rendered or redirected
2017-10-11T02:59:33.556911+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:33.556843 #4]  INFO -- : [eaf81f4a-ddfc-441b-bf61-537208d2fae1] Completed 302 Found in 1ms
2017-10-11T02:59:33.672073+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=damp-ravine-93217.herokuapp.com request_id=68bd1991-d208-4431-8c26-f4e1c1740f18 fwd="68.113.36.43" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=8ms status=302 bytes=806 protocol=https
2017-10-11T02:59:33.556658+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=damp-ravine-93217.herokuapp.com request_id=eaf81f4a-ddfc-441b-bf61-537208d2fae1 fwd="68.113.36.43" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=302 bytes=806 protocol=https
2017-10-11T02:59:33.780386+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=damp-ravine-93217.herokuapp.com request_id=51814dfc-a0c2-48f3-a3e1-331bcbc389c5 fwd="68.113.36.43" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=302 bytes=806 protocol=https
2017-10-11T02:59:33.667278+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:33.667197 #4]  INFO -- : [68bd1991-d208-4431-8c26-f4e1c1740f18] Started GET "/" for 68.113.36.43 at 2017-10-11 02:59:33 +0000
2017-10-11T02:59:33.670929+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:33.670860 #4]  INFO -- : [68bd1991-d208-4431-8c26-f4e1c1740f18] Processing by ArticlesController#index as HTML
2017-10-11T02:59:33.671910+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:33.671841 #4]  INFO -- : [68bd1991-d208-4431-8c26-f4e1c1740f18] Redirected to https://damp-ravine-93217.herokuapp.com/
2017-10-11T02:59:33.672109+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:33.672044 #4]  INFO -- : [68bd1991-d208-4431-8c26-f4e1c1740f18] Filter chain halted as :require_login rendered or redirected
2017-10-11T02:59:33.672303+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:33.672237 #4]  INFO -- : [68bd1991-d208-4431-8c26-f4e1c1740f18] Completed 302 Found in 1ms
2017-10-11T02:59:33.778413+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:33.778311 #4]  INFO -- : [51814dfc-a0c2-48f3-a3e1-331bcbc389c5] Started GET "/" for 68.113.36.43 at 2017-10-11 02:59:33 +0000
2017-10-11T02:59:33.779416+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:33.779346 #4]  INFO -- : [51814dfc-a0c2-48f3-a3e1-331bcbc389c5] Processing by ArticlesController#index as HTML
2017-10-11T02:59:33.780363+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:33.780295 #4]  INFO -- : [51814dfc-a0c2-48f3-a3e1-331bcbc389c5] Redirected to https://damp-ravine-93217.herokuapp.com/
2017-10-11T02:59:33.780561+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:33.780485 #4]  INFO -- : [51814dfc-a0c2-48f3-a3e1-331bcbc389c5] Filter chain halted as :require_login rendered or redirected
2017-10-11T02:59:33.780741+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:33.780677 #4]  INFO -- : [51814dfc-a0c2-48f3-a3e1-331bcbc389c5] Completed 302 Found in 1ms
2017-10-11T02:59:33.885106+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:33.885000 #4]  INFO -- : [e5f1f408-ff92-4aac-bfaf-76277fdf25e6] Started GET "/" for 68.113.36.43 at 2017-10-11 02:59:33 +0000
2017-10-11T02:59:33.885946+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:33.885871 #4]  INFO -- : [e5f1f408-ff92-4aac-bfaf-76277fdf25e6] Processing by ArticlesController#index as HTML
2017-10-11T02:59:33.887290+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:33.887205 #4]  INFO -- : [e5f1f408-ff92-4aac-bfaf-76277fdf25e6] Redirected to https://damp-ravine-93217.herokuapp.com/
2017-10-11T02:59:33.887536+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:33.887381 #4]  INFO -- : [e5f1f408-ff92-4aac-bfaf-76277fdf25e6] Filter chain halted as :require_login rendered or redirected
2017-10-11T02:59:33.887596+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:33.887526 #4]  INFO -- : [e5f1f408-ff92-4aac-bfaf-76277fdf25e6] Completed 302 Found in 2ms
2017-10-11T02:59:33.887516+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=damp-ravine-93217.herokuapp.com request_id=e5f1f408-ff92-4aac-bfaf-76277fdf25e6 fwd="68.113.36.43" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=302 bytes=806 protocol=https
2017-10-11T02:59:33.994875+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=damp-ravine-93217.herokuapp.com request_id=6ed7cd7a-2d41-4296-8908-0e10d0971fa4 fwd="68.113.36.43" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=302 bytes=806 protocol=https
2017-10-11T02:59:33.993235+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:33.993145 #4]  INFO -- : [6ed7cd7a-2d41-4296-8908-0e10d0971fa4] Started GET "/" for 68.113.36.43 at 2017-10-11 02:59:33 +0000
2017-10-11T02:59:33.995176+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:33.995112 #4]  INFO -- : [6ed7cd7a-2d41-4296-8908-0e10d0971fa4] Filter chain halted as :require_login rendered or redirected
2017-10-11T02:59:34.102471+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:34.102387 #4]  INFO -- : [8aba1587-469b-43dd-a0e6-e062f96f63a0] Redirected to https://damp-ravine-93217.herokuapp.com/
2017-10-11T02:59:34.102595+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:34.102537 #4]  INFO -- : [8aba1587-469b-43dd-a0e6-e062f96f63a0] Filter chain halted as :require_login rendered or redirected
2017-10-11T02:59:34.099513+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:34.099372 #4]  INFO -- : [8aba1587-469b-43dd-a0e6-e062f96f63a0] Started GET "/" for 68.113.36.43 at 2017-10-11 02:59:34 +0000
2017-10-11T02:59:34.208056+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:34.207953 #4]  INFO -- : [12eb086b-1a23-4378-92c1-e2a4ad9f4615] Started GET "/" for 68.113.36.43 at 2017-10-11 02:59:34 +0000
2017-10-11T02:59:34.101425+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:34.101355 #4]  INFO -- : [8aba1587-469b-43dd-a0e6-e062f96f63a0] Processing by ArticlesController#index as HTML
2017-10-11T02:59:33.995326+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:33.995263 #4]  INFO -- : [6ed7cd7a-2d41-4296-8908-0e10d0971fa4] Completed 302 Found in 1ms
2017-10-11T02:59:34.208930+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:34.208843 #4]  INFO -- : [12eb086b-1a23-4378-92c1-e2a4ad9f4615] Processing by ArticlesController#index as HTML
2017-10-11T02:59:33.995046+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:33.994954 #4]  INFO -- : [6ed7cd7a-2d41-4296-8908-0e10d0971fa4] Redirected to https://damp-ravine-93217.herokuapp.com/
2017-10-11T02:59:34.210082+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:34.210012 #4]  INFO -- : [12eb086b-1a23-4378-92c1-e2a4ad9f4615] Filter chain halted as :require_login rendered or redirected
2017-10-11T02:59:34.210297+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:34.210231 #4]  INFO -- : [12eb086b-1a23-4378-92c1-e2a4ad9f4615] Completed 302 Found in 1ms
2017-10-11T02:59:34.209918+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:34.209834 #4]  INFO -- : [12eb086b-1a23-4378-92c1-e2a4ad9f4615] Redirected to https://damp-ravine-93217.herokuapp.com/
2017-10-11T02:59:34.102719+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:34.102660 #4]  INFO -- : [8aba1587-469b-43dd-a0e6-e062f96f63a0] Completed 302 Found in 1ms
2017-10-11T02:59:33.994117+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:33.994046 #4]  INFO -- : [6ed7cd7a-2d41-4296-8908-0e10d0971fa4] Processing by ArticlesController#index as HTML
2017-10-11T02:59:34.102038+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=damp-ravine-93217.herokuapp.com request_id=8aba1587-469b-43dd-a0e6-e062f96f63a0 fwd="68.113.36.43" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=302 bytes=806 protocol=https
2017-10-11T02:59:34.209930+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=damp-ravine-93217.herokuapp.com request_id=12eb086b-1a23-4378-92c1-e2a4ad9f4615 fwd="68.113.36.43" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=302 bytes=806 protocol=https
2017-10-11T02:59:34.320370+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=damp-ravine-93217.herokuapp.com request_id=75bf3a5d-5cfc-4463-b974-3724de6a4f71 fwd="68.113.36.43" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=302 bytes=806 protocol=https
2017-10-11T02:59:34.460365+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=damp-ravine-93217.herokuapp.com request_id=cc1d3677-36f3-4d07-ad96-132699b5f1c8 fwd="68.113.36.43" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=10ms status=302 bytes=806 protocol=https
2017-10-11T02:59:34.318036+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:34.317944 #4]  INFO -- : [75bf3a5d-5cfc-4463-b974-3724de6a4f71] Started GET "/" for 68.113.36.43 at 2017-10-11 02:59:34 +0000
2017-10-11T02:59:34.319197+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:34.319046 #4]  INFO -- : [75bf3a5d-5cfc-4463-b974-3724de6a4f71] Processing by ArticlesController#index as HTML
2017-10-11T02:59:34.320563+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:34.320475 #4]  INFO -- : [75bf3a5d-5cfc-4463-b974-3724de6a4f71] Redirected to https://damp-ravine-93217.herokuapp.com/
2017-10-11T02:59:34.320700+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:34.320632 #4]  INFO -- : [75bf3a5d-5cfc-4463-b974-3724de6a4f71] Filter chain halted as :require_login rendered or redirected
2017-10-11T02:59:34.320857+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:34.320787 #4]  INFO -- : [75bf3a5d-5cfc-4463-b974-3724de6a4f71] Completed 302 Found in 1ms
2017-10-11T02:59:34.455793+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:34.455706 #4]  INFO -- : [cc1d3677-36f3-4d07-ad96-132699b5f1c8] Started GET "/" for 68.113.36.43 at 2017-10-11 02:59:34 +0000
2017-10-11T02:59:34.457460+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:34.457268 #4]  INFO -- : [cc1d3677-36f3-4d07-ad96-132699b5f1c8] Processing by ArticlesController#index as HTML
2017-10-11T02:59:34.458665+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:34.458603 #4]  INFO -- : [cc1d3677-36f3-4d07-ad96-132699b5f1c8] Redirected to https://damp-ravine-93217.herokuapp.com/
2017-10-11T02:59:34.458857+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:34.458801 #4]  INFO -- : [cc1d3677-36f3-4d07-ad96-132699b5f1c8] Filter chain halted as :require_login rendered or redirected
2017-10-11T02:59:34.459070+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:34.458988 #4]  INFO -- : [cc1d3677-36f3-4d07-ad96-132699b5f1c8] Completed 302 Found in 1ms
2017-10-11T02:59:34.566942+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:34.566845 #4]  INFO -- : [42d5b3f0-2416-4fac-b78f-0e34b30737e3] Started GET "/" for 68.113.36.43 at 2017-10-11 02:59:34 +0000
2017-10-11T02:59:34.567743+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:34.567679 #4]  INFO -- : [42d5b3f0-2416-4fac-b78f-0e34b30737e3] Processing by ArticlesController#index as HTML
2017-10-11T02:59:34.572470+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=damp-ravine-93217.herokuapp.com request_id=42d5b3f0-2416-4fac-b78f-0e34b30737e3 fwd="68.113.36.43" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=9ms status=302 bytes=806 protocol=https
2017-10-11T02:59:34.568784+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:34.568720 #4]  INFO -- : [42d5b3f0-2416-4fac-b78f-0e34b30737e3] Redirected to https://damp-ravine-93217.herokuapp.com/
2017-10-11T02:59:34.572487+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:34.572420 #4]  INFO -- : [42d5b3f0-2416-4fac-b78f-0e34b30737e3] Completed 302 Found in 4ms
2017-10-11T02:59:34.572307+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:34.572202 #4]  INFO -- : [42d5b3f0-2416-4fac-b78f-0e34b30737e3] Filter chain halted as :require_login rendered or redirected
2017-10-11T02:59:34.680103+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:34.680016 #4]  INFO -- : [36a18c52-458e-4827-9151-5c9e35888312] Started GET "/" for 68.113.36.43 at 2017-10-11 02:59:34 +0000
2017-10-11T02:59:34.680711+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:34.680654 #4]  INFO -- : [36a18c52-458e-4827-9151-5c9e35888312] Processing by ArticlesController#index as HTML
2017-10-11T02:59:34.681476+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:34.681412 #4]  INFO -- : [36a18c52-458e-4827-9151-5c9e35888312] Redirected to https://damp-ravine-93217.herokuapp.com/
2017-10-11T02:59:34.681607+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:34.681549 #4]  INFO -- : [36a18c52-458e-4827-9151-5c9e35888312] Filter chain halted as :require_login rendered or redirected
2017-10-11T02:59:34.681794+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:34.681729 #4]  INFO -- : [36a18c52-458e-4827-9151-5c9e35888312] Completed 302 Found in 1ms
2017-10-11T02:59:34.788498+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:34.788400 #4]  INFO -- : [9652f0eb-d9f3-4c49-a717-34413979584e] Started GET "/" for 68.113.36.43 at 2017-10-11 02:59:34 +0000
2017-10-11T02:59:34.789160+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:34.789093 #4]  INFO -- : [9652f0eb-d9f3-4c49-a717-34413979584e] Processing by ArticlesController#index as HTML
2017-10-11T02:59:34.790212+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:34.790123 #4]  INFO -- : [9652f0eb-d9f3-4c49-a717-34413979584e] Redirected to https://damp-ravine-93217.herokuapp.com/
2017-10-11T02:59:34.790400+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:34.790334 #4]  INFO -- : [9652f0eb-d9f3-4c49-a717-34413979584e] Filter chain halted as :require_login rendered or redirected
2017-10-11T02:59:34.791145+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:34.791078 #4]  INFO -- : [9652f0eb-d9f3-4c49-a717-34413979584e] Completed 302 Found in 2ms
2017-10-11T02:59:34.681813+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=damp-ravine-93217.herokuapp.com request_id=36a18c52-458e-4827-9151-5c9e35888312 fwd="68.113.36.43" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=302 bytes=806 protocol=https
2017-10-11T02:59:34.790762+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=damp-ravine-93217.herokuapp.com request_id=9652f0eb-d9f3-4c49-a717-34413979584e fwd="68.113.36.43" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=302 bytes=806 protocol=https
2017-10-11T02:59:34.896945+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=damp-ravine-93217.herokuapp.com request_id=a9a7945b-84e3-4231-b6eb-62560a0bc631 fwd="68.113.36.43" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=302 bytes=806 protocol=https
2017-10-11T02:59:35.010268+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=damp-ravine-93217.herokuapp.com request_id=2e890718-57d3-474f-bbc9-a713d0708c23 fwd="68.113.36.43" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=6ms status=302 bytes=806 protocol=https
2017-10-11T02:59:34.895229+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:34.895124 #4]  INFO -- : [a9a7945b-84e3-4231-b6eb-62560a0bc631] Started GET "/" for 68.113.36.43 at 2017-10-11 02:59:34 +0000
2017-10-11T02:59:34.896075+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:34.896002 #4]  INFO -- : [a9a7945b-84e3-4231-b6eb-62560a0bc631] Processing by ArticlesController#index as HTML
2017-10-11T02:59:34.897002+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:34.896931 #4]  INFO -- : [a9a7945b-84e3-4231-b6eb-62560a0bc631] Redirected to https://damp-ravine-93217.herokuapp.com/
2017-10-11T02:59:34.897163+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:34.897094 #4]  INFO -- : [a9a7945b-84e3-4231-b6eb-62560a0bc631] Filter chain halted as :require_login rendered or redirected
2017-10-11T02:59:34.897339+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:34.897272 #4]  INFO -- : [a9a7945b-84e3-4231-b6eb-62560a0bc631] Completed 302 Found in 1ms
2017-10-11T02:59:35.008260+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:35.008166 #4]  INFO -- : [2e890718-57d3-474f-bbc9-a713d0708c23] Started GET "/" for 68.113.36.43 at 2017-10-11 02:59:35 +0000
2017-10-11T02:59:35.009086+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:35.009011 #4]  INFO -- : [2e890718-57d3-474f-bbc9-a713d0708c23] Processing by ArticlesController#index as HTML
2017-10-11T02:59:35.009992+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:35.009917 #4]  INFO -- : [2e890718-57d3-474f-bbc9-a713d0708c23] Redirected to https://damp-ravine-93217.herokuapp.com/
2017-10-11T02:59:35.010130+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:35.010072 #4]  INFO -- : [2e890718-57d3-474f-bbc9-a713d0708c23] Filter chain halted as :require_login rendered or redirected
2017-10-11T02:59:35.010329+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:35.010265 #4]  INFO -- : [2e890718-57d3-474f-bbc9-a713d0708c23] Completed 302 Found in 1ms
2017-10-11T02:59:35.118349+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:35.118270 #4]  INFO -- : [72ef8cbe-e258-4e4e-aee3-17c62b55c1c5] Started GET "/" for 68.113.36.43 at 2017-10-11 02:59:35 +0000
2017-10-11T02:59:35.119024+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:35.118962 #4]  INFO -- : [72ef8cbe-e258-4e4e-aee3-17c62b55c1c5] Processing by ArticlesController#index as HTML
2017-10-11T02:59:35.119822+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:35.119759 #4]  INFO -- : [72ef8cbe-e258-4e4e-aee3-17c62b55c1c5] Redirected to https://damp-ravine-93217.herokuapp.com/
2017-10-11T02:59:35.119960+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:35.119895 #4]  INFO -- : [72ef8cbe-e258-4e4e-aee3-17c62b55c1c5] Filter chain halted as :require_login rendered or redirected
2017-10-11T02:59:35.120087+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-11T02:59:35.120032 #4]  INFO -- : [72ef8cbe-e258-4e4e-aee3-17c62b55c1c5] Completed 302 Found in 1ms
2017-10-11T02:59:35.119487+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=damp-ravine-93217.herokuapp.com request_id=72ef8cbe-e258-4e4e-aee3-17c62b55c1c5 fwd="68.113.36.43" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=302 bytes=806 protocol=https
```

Here is my articles controller:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController 
   include ArticlesHelper 
   before_action :require_login, except[:destroy, :create, :edit, :update, :new] 
   def index 
     @articles = Article.all 
   end 
   def show 
     @article = Article.find(params[:id]) 
     @comment = Comment.new 
     @comment.article_id = @article.id 
   end 
   def new 
     @article = Article.new 
   end 
   def create 
     @article = Article.new(article_params) 
     @article.save 
     flash.notice = "Article #{@article.title} Created" 
     redirect_to article_path(@article) 
   end 
   def destroy 
     @article = Article.find(params[:id]) 
     @article.destroy 
     flash.notice = "Article #{@article.title} Deleted" 
     redirect_to articles_path 
   end 
   def edit 
   @article= Article.find(params[:id]) 
   end 
   def update 
     @article=Article.find(params[:id]) 
     @article.update(article_params) 
     flash.notice = "Article #{@article.title} Updated" 
     redirect_to article_path(@article) 
   end 




end
```

Sorry in advance for bad formating. This is my first question in Stackoverflow, and I have yet to have a chance to get some practice in.

edit: Also might help to mention that It works fine in local host.

Comment: show your articles controller

Comment: @Mason, you might be using redrect_to and render in the wrong way.It would be better if you include the controller code above.

Comment: show your controller

Comment: Updated to show articles controller. Thanks for the quick responses!